# Configure solr for bm25 similarity

Tags: apache, solr, lucene

i would configure solr http://lucene.apache.org/solr/ for use bm25 model to analyze my collection.

I tried to look for guides or tutorials but i have not found anything about it. Can you help me to explain how configure and execute queries with this model?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can configure the similarity class in your `schema.xml` configuration file:

```
<similarity class="org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.BM25Similarity" />
```

This is the same was you'd implement your own similarity class.

The [API documentation for the Lucene similarity classes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_4_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/Similarity.html) shows the list of existing scorers and what you'd need to to if you want to make custom implementations in the future.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, where is the schema.xml file? Because, searching it, i found several files in my solr folder

Comment: @user2520969 It's usually located under the 'conf' directory of your collection.

Comment: I've configured solr (version 5.4) through the command "bin/solr start -e cloud -noprompt" but in the cloud folder there is no conf folder. Although, the conf folder is present in the other folders, so, have i run another command to start solr?

Comment: Then you'll have to [use the Schema API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API).